# Encoding issue: vbscript "Chr()" to .Net C#

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, vbscript

I can't seem to find the answer to this question.

It seems like I should be able to go from a number to a character in C# by simply doing something along the lines of (char)MyInt to duplicate the behaviour of vb's Chr() function; however, this is not the case:

In VB Script w/ an asp page, if my code says this:

```
Response.Write(Chr(139))
```

It outputs this:

```
‹ (character code 8249)
```

Opposed to this:

> (character code 139)

I'm missing something somewhere with the encoding, but I can't find it.  What encoding is Chr() using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Chr()` uses the system default encoding, I believe - so it's *roughly* equivalent to:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 139 };
char c = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes)[0];
```

On my box (Windows CP1252 as the default) that does indeed give Unicode 8249.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call something that has exactly the behaviour of VB's Chr from C#, then, why not simply call it rather than trying to deduce its behaviour?

Just put a "using Microsoft.VisualBasic;" at the top of your C# program, add the VB runtime DLL to your references, and go to town.

Answer (score 1):

If you cast an `int` to a `char`, you will get the character with the Unicode character code that was in the integer. The `char` data type is just a 16 bit UTF-16 character code.

To get the equivalent of the VBScript chr() function in .NET you would need something like:

```
string s = Encoding.Default.GetString(new byte[]{ 139 });
```